# Vb.Net compare two Access Data tables for differences

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I've created a piece of code that allows me to populate a data table after looping through some information. I would then like to compare it with the information that was gathered the last time the tool was executed and copy the information in to a new data table. Finally the code will then take a copy of the new information gathered in order to have it checked for next time. The system should basically work like this:

1. Get new information
2. Compare against last times information
3. Copy information from task 1 ready for next time task 2 is done.

I've done some reading up and a lot of `Inner Joins` are being thrown about, but my understanding of this is that it will return fields that are the same, not different.

How would I go about attempting this?

**Update**
I forgot to mention that I've already achieved steps 1 and 3, I can store the data, copy the data for the next run, but can't do step 2, comparing the data

Comment: @DanielCook Thanks for the vote to close, Im sorry I didn't explicitly say I was looking for some help in HOW to achieve this, not just is it possible... I'll edit my question to suit

Comment: This is probably too broad. But it sounds like you're going to have to have a 2nd table to store the information for the prior run, which you simply overwrite in step 3. As for the comparisons, its unclear how you're wanting to compare. If you were to use inner joins as you mention, you'd likely do it on the primary key (if that makes sense for your information).

Comment: Sounds like maybe an Archive table would be what you are looking for.  With each transaction to a table(new, update or delete) you store all the previous data as it was prior to the change.  One table is live and has a single record.  2nd table has multiple entries for each live entry representing a point in time.

Comment: I would say make your plan to the best of your abilities, try your own step 1, if you run into issues post about that particular issue, then rinse and repeat until you are completed.   Generally as soon as I read something like "How would I go about doing this?" type of questions I just go along my merry way.  Don't really have time to write a book if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a SQL "Describe table" query to get the structure?

If you are talking about differences in the records contained, then you will need to keep an "old data" table and your current data table and do a right or left join to find data that is in one but not the other.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about the actual records, the structure is identical. I have a copy of the old table and am looking to get the differences between the new copy and the old copy

Comment: Then you need to look into right/left joins and archiving your current data for the next run. Use "CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; " to establish the archive table. Once that is done use "TRUNCATE table" to wipe it out before using "INSERT newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable;" to refill it. I trust that you understand how to execute SQL statements through VB.